# 301 редирект с одной страницы на другую на разных доменах через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект, http-status-code-301

Нужно перенаправить 301 со страницы https://old.site/cat/blabla/page.html на https://new.site/category/item.html, т.е., адреса страниц старого и нового сайта не одинаковы.
Делал так, на старом сайте в htaccess:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Redirect 301 /cat/blabla/page.html https://new.site/category/item.html [R=301,L]
</ifModule>
```

Получается ошибка Internal Server Error даже без указания номера. В чём может быть проблема? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

вам либо надо юзать [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) тогда редирект выглядит следующим образом (флаг `L` тут смысла иметь не будет, поскольку редирект внешний)

```
RewriteRule /cat/... https://.... [R=301]
```

Либо использовать [`mod_alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

```
Redirect 301 /cat/... https://....
```